# Do indiscernibles imply additional non-stardard models?

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, nonstandard-models

From Wikipedia Indiscernibles are objects which cannot be distinguished by any property or relation defined by a formula. Usually only first-order formulas are considered.

Question: does the existence of indiscernibles  mean that even in first order formal system for which all the set of true formulae are known, we will still have an infinite number of non-standard models? Those models would be the models in which the indiscernibles would have different second order properties but of course the same first order ones.

Comment: I don't understand something - every consistent first-order theory has infinitely many non-isomorphic models, even if we don't assume that there are indiscernibles in the "standard" model.

Comment: @Wojowu I had the wrong idea that, for instance, all the models of true arithmetic (at the expense of being noncomputable indefinible, etc) were isomorphic to each other (to N), that there were not any  non-standard models for it. But I am not so sure now. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/True_arithmetic

Comment: Löwenheim–Skolem theorem guarantees that given any structure (e.g. a model of a theory) then there are structures satifying precisely the same first-order statements of any cardinality. Of course, structures of different sizes can't be isomorphic. For more, see Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem

Comment: @Wojowu if you put (copy paste) your comments into an answer an there are no other good answers I'll give you the bounty, it would be a shame to loose that reputation points into thin air.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By [Löwenheim–Skolem theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/L%C3%B6wenheim%E2%80%93Skolem_theorem), if we have any infinite model $M$ of a first-order theory $T$ (it can be anything, ranging from PA to $Th(\Bbb N)$ and things like that, the theory doesn't have to be recursive or even countable) then there are arbitrarily large (in terms of cardinality) models $M'$ satisfy precisely the same first-order statements as $M$, so in particular are also models of $T$.

Of course, models of different cardinalities can't be isomorphic, as isomorphism has to, in particulat, be a bijection between underlying sets.

Note that this result does *not* depend in any way on existence of indiscernibles in $M$.

Comment: Thanks Wojowu, pretty clear answer! I am forced by the site to wait a day before I can give (or award) the bounty. So, check tomorrrow.

Comment: @Wolphramjonny Thanks a lot :)